# OpenTk OpenGl texture coordinate pointer not working

Tags: c#, opengl, 3d, rendering, opentk

I pass the vertices to a buffer and the texture coordinates to an another buffer the vertices are draw perfectly, but the texture coordinate pointer is not doing anything, but in an another project it works without problems, I tried to copy from the other project but nothing happened. It produces the same problem without throwing any errors. However, it works perfectly in the immediate drawing mode.

[image: this]

```cs
void renderFrame(object o, FrameEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear screen
    GL.Translate(Input.GetMoveDir(.1f));
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

    GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureWrapT, (int)TextureWrapMode.Repeat);
    //Render image

    //Enable thing before use
    GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, texture.ID);
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Texture2D);
    //Setup blending
    GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);
    GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactor.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactor.OneMinusSrcAlpha);

    // Immedaiate test

    /*GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);

    for (int i = 0; i < vertexBuffer.Length; i++)
    {
        GL.Normal3(normalBuffer[i]);
        GL.TexCoord2(uvBuffer[i]);
        GL.Vertex3(vertexBuffer[i]);
    }

    GL.End();*/

    //Enable arrays

    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.VertexArray);
    GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.TextureCoordArray);
    //GL.EnableClientState(ArrayCap.NormalArray);

    //GL.Color3(Color.Red);

    //Set vertex pointer
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VEB);
    GL.VertexPointer(3, VertexPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);

    //Set uv pointer

    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, UVB);
    GL.TexCoordPointer(2, TexCoordPointerType.Float, Vector2.SizeInBytes, 0);

    //Set normal pointer

    /*GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, NOB);
    GL.NormalPointer(NormalPointerType.Float, Vector3.SizeInBytes, 0);*/

    //Draw
    GL.DrawArrays(PrimitiveType.Quads, 0, vertexBuffer.Length);

    // Swap buffers
    GL.Flush();
    window.SwapBuffers();
}

public void UpdateBuffers(Vector3[] vertices, Vector2[] uvs, Vector3[] normals)
{
    //Vertex buffer

    vertexBuffer = vertices;
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, VEB);
    GL.BufferSubData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)0, (int)(Vector3.SizeInBytes * vertexBuffer.Length), vertexBuffer);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

    //Uv buffer

    uvBuffer = uvs;
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, UVB);
    GL.BufferSubData<Vector2>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)0, (int)(Vector2.SizeInBytes * uvBuffer.Length), uvBuffer);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

    //Normal buffer

    normalBuffer = normals;
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, NOB);
    GL.BufferSubData<Vector3>(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (IntPtr)0, (int)(Vector3.SizeInBytes * normalBuffer.Length), normalBuffer);
    GL.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, 0);

    Console.WriteLine("Buffers updated");
}
```

Comment: So you set `TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter`?

Comment: I changed it to this: 'GL.TexParameter(TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureParameterName.TextureMinFilter, pixelated ? (int)
                TextureMinFilter.Nearest : (int)TextureMinFilter.Linear);'

Comment: Yes that's ok. If you don't generate mipmaps, then you have to set the parameter to `TextureMinFilter.Nearest` or `TextureMinFilter.Linear`. Else the texture would be mipmap incomplete and cannot be sampled.

Comment: Are you sure that the image is loaded correctly and the that the texture is not all black?

Comment: If I not draw whit arrays it works completly fine

Comment: Note, the size of a buffer is immutable. The buffer update seems to be correct, but how do you create the buffer objects data store?

Comment: Do you set a white color (`GL.Color3(Color.White);`) before drawing the mesh?

Comment: Nothing happened.